# Excel 2013 ListObject

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, listobject

I am trying to add two ListObjects side by side to a WorkSheet.

Method 1
Do this in the Visual Studio designer and then bind data to the first ListObject, the second ListObject gets bumped over to the right - is there a way to fix it's location??

Method 2
I have tried adding the ListObject to a range in the code-behind but this has another annoying side-effect that it leaves a blank row at the top of the ListObject even though I set the ShowHeaders to false. Is there a way to get rid of this blank row??

I don't want the automatic column names as I want friendly names for the user, not what I'm using in my code.

Regards
Alan

Comment: you need to show the code you have to possibly get any support...

Comment: The first part of my question simply relates to dropping ListObjects onto the Visual Studio Excel Workbook designer. I am dropping the ListObject onto a single cell (the top left of where I want the ListObject) - there is no code involved.

Comment: The second part of my question simply uses the basic method of adding ListObjects to a Sheet using the Sheet1_Startup method.  `lstOne = this.Controls.AddListObject(this.get_Range("A5","J5"), "lstOne");
 lstOne.AutoSetDataBoundColumnHeaders = false;
 lstOne.ShowAutoFilter = false;
 lstOne.ShowHeaders = false;

 lstTwo = this.Controls.AddListObject(this.get_Range("$L$5:$U$5"), "lstTwo");
 lstTwo.AutoSetDataBoundColumnHeaders = false;
 lstTwo.ShowHeaders = false;` Data binding is done via SetDataBinding method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I add the ListObject to a highlighted range of cells then it would not push other objects out of the way. However I did not want headers and when you disable these you are left with a blank row. I simply copied the ListObject cells and pasted them into the row above.

Regards
Alan